# add RESTfull capabilities to meteor

Tags: meteor

Whatever the path entered in the browser, the meteor app always returns a template. How can one add routing to enable RESTfull capabilities in a meteor app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my quest to add RESTfull capabilities to my meteor app, I cam accross meter-router which is a great meteorite smart package.

here is a short explanation on how to get it and how to access the body part of a POST:

meteor will add RESTfull capabilities before the 1.0 release. In the mean time, you have to use meter-router. This
article explains how to do that.

Follow the instructions in [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router)

In the server-side routing part, it is not explained how to get to the parameters in the request body. This took me
some time to figure out so here it is:

assuming you use the following form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/test" method="POST">
    <input value="titi" name="testme"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The content of the `testme` field will be located in `this.request.body.testme`. Here is a sample that will return some text with the content of the field

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
       Meteor.Router.add('/test', 'POST', function () {
           return "called with "+ this.request.body.testme + "\n";
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[meteor-collectionapi](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi) may suite your needs. It adds a wrapper around your collections in order to expose them via REST.

Comment: the collection API is great to send Mongo queries to a meteor app but is not suited for RESTful access to the application.